# Graphics distorted in QVGA Android phone

Tags: android

i made an application in android 2.1
when i run my application in QVGA simulator its Button,TabBars and EditText Field are Distroted from both ends
but they seems to be perfect in HVGA.
whats the problem. and how can i resolve it.

Thnk!
[image: device002]

[image: device001]s

You can see in the image that the edit Text Field is Distorted from both ends
same is the case with buttons and same is the case with TabBars.. you can see both images
in comapre see the 3rd image .this is from HVGA.. this does not have any distortion in textfields or buttons or tab bars..
[image: device003]

Comment: how distorted? post a screenshot or describe it more precisely, so we can help you.

Comment: how can i add pic in this post please guide

Comment: done with the editing phase.. please guide for my problem

Comment: I still dont' unterstand your problem, can you make two screenshots from HVGA and QVGA for comparison?

Comment: can u see in the 2nd image that the Model textField on Top is distorted from both ends.. this only happends in QVGA but in HVGA my text fields are Normal..

Comment: Oh, I see. You may want to edit the image to highlight the distortion with an arrow or something. Does this happen all the time? Have you tried putting it on an actual phone screen to see if it happens there? Edit: I edited the image for you :)

Comment: this happens in real mobiles as well

Answer (score 0):

apply `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />`  in AndroidManifest.xml

refer http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html for risks